# Calling init function from another function

Tags: go, rfc

why i can't call `init` function from the other function, `init()` is just function right, why i can't just call the `init` function, should i change golang RFC to make it happend

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

func main() {
    go init()
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

error :

```
./prog.go:12:8: undefined: init
```

Comment: `init`, like `main`, is a special function. If you want to be able to call its functionality from elsewhere, put it in a different function, and call that function from `init`.

Comment: `init()` functions are special as [described in the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization). A function with that name cannot be called by application code.  Fix your application by using a different name for the function.  Note that the above program has another issue: there's not guarantee that the goroutine will execute before the program exits.

Comment: [As the spec says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization): "the init identifier can be used only to declare init functions, yet the identifier itself is not declared. Thus init functions cannot be referred to from anywhere in a program." This is intentional on the part of the language designers.

Comment: that's totally different question @tim-cooper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Package initialization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization)
>
> the init identifier can be used only to declare init functions, yet
>   the identifier itself is not declared. Thus init functions cannot be
>   referred to from anywhere in a program.

---

To accomplish your objective, call a function.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func init() {
    f("init")
}

func f(s string) {
    fmt.Printf("f(%q)\n", s)
}

func main() {
    f("main")
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/isyrCIeYCV4

Output:

```
f("init")
f("main")
```

Answer (score -1):

init can not called, it will run when package loaded.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
func main(){
}
```

result: Hello, playground